# What is the rationale for showing the "modified by" user in the questions list?

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation

On some question list pages, the "asked" text is replaced by "modified", and the user displayed next to the question is the user who modified the question, not the user who originally asked the question.

I understand that this indicates a question has been modified, but I don't understand why the asker's name needs to be swept off of the question list. I also understand that it shows who made the most recent change to the question, but I don't understand why that would be important enough to display so prominently.

I am not asking this in order to make a statement about rep disparities between users (as [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15493/modified-by-displayed-on-question-screen-instead-of-user-asking-question) was likely intended to do). I just don't like that I'm forced to read carefully to see whether the user displayed in the list is the OP or just someone who made an edit to the question (even if it's merely a trivial edit). It's a matter of consistency and relevancy.

To me, this would make more sense:

- In question lists, always display the user who asked the question. (I.e., only display either the "asked" tag or the "community wiki" tag.)
- If the question has been modified, display an unobtrusive icon somewhere on the question list to indicate this. The name of the user who last modified the question could go next to the icon.

Are there reasons behind this design choice other than the ones I have considered?

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65179/active-questions-name-should-reflect-original-poster-and-editor-if-exists. It suggests that in the active sort, the original poster's name should always be attributed in some fashion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for showing the modifying user's name on the Questions List is because you're looking at the Active Sort - this sort explicitly orders things by what was most recently modified. If you check any of the other sort orders (votes, newest, hot, etc.), they show the original asker.

Without it, the sorting of the posts on that view would be very difficult to discern - you see something bumped to the top, but then you'd have to click into the post to see who actually caused it to be bumped. This keeps the most pertinent information to that specific sort view (the latest editor) immediately visible to users.