# Why are editor names displayed so prominently?

Tags: feature-request, edits, user-interface

Ever since the editing restrictions were loosened a few months ago, I've started to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534977/jquery-and-other-library-right-order-to-include) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095546/what-is-the-relationship-between-flex-flash-and-actionscript-3-0) [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047597/file-in-h-what-does-it-resolve-to) [passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662527/making-file-dialog-only-accept-directories). It's always something simple, like code formatting or a grammar fix.

But does anyone (aside from the approving moderator) care *who* edited the post?

[image: Overly large attribution for a minor edit]

As you can see in the image, my name is displayed as large as (and arguably, as prominently as) the original author's. It's almost misleading for [minor edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5047597/revisions).

I am by no means suggesting that this information be made unavailable. Rather, a simple, unobtrusive link to the [revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5047597/revisions) should suffice. The text could continue to attribute the most recent author, date, or it could simply say "Revision History". This change would shift visual attention back to the original author. Yet, it would still be visually apparent that the post had been altered by the community. For example:

[image: Simple revision history link]

What do others think? Is there a reason edits are displayed so prominently?

*Puts on flame retardant suit*

Comment: Semi-related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73996/

Comment: Thanks @Jason Plank. c.f. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/65179/active-questions-name-should-reflect-original-poster-and-editor-if-exists. Despite @Grace Note's responses, I see I'm not the first to find this to be a slightly odd UX

Comment: No freehand circles, eh? No wonder you're wearing the flame retardant suit.

Comment: @Adam - fixed that for you

Comment: I agree completely; I'd thought the same thing.

Comment: I have, on multiple occasions, mistaken the editor for the OP.  I also would like the editor less prominent.

Comment: +1 I put my email in my profile and on more than one occasion, I've received mail from people who thought I posted a question when I merely edited it. I've made similar mistakes myself.

Comment: @Farseeker Why do I never get the chance to use my M2-2?

Comment: @muntoo - I'd have to know what an M2-2 was in order to answer that ;)

Answer (score 25):

We editors don't get much for our troubles.

If we haven't yet earned 1000 reputation from editing (and they're below 2000, I believe) we get reputation for editing. Otherwise, no reputation.

Editors also get badges, three to be exact.

But other than that? The tireless work of making posts better and garnering the OP upvotes gets us very little, so I like that our names are displayed front and center.

Comment: Ok, I respect that. But do you then disagree that the "Edited" block distracts from credit due to the original poster? I ask this not because I don't want your name shown :-) But because I often scan the page *for* this information -- specifically the original poster's rep (because low rep may be indicative of someone who posts questions before exhausting other resources). Big things catch users' eyes.

Comment: Every time I edit, my OCD is calmed and my dark passenger silences until I see the next one. That's my incentive for editing.

Comment: @Farseeker: You have a dark passenger, like me?

Comment: @Dexter - Your family and friends always seem to die in some horrible fashion, and sometimes at your own hand. Please, feel free not be my friend.

Comment: @Farseeker Do all frequent editors have OCD? :P

Comment: @muntoo Yes.  Yes we do.

Answer (score 13):

After you've edited a post, it's partially yours. Not primarily, and certainly not entirely, but... If you did a good job, you deserve some credit, and if you messed up, you certainly deserve some of the blame.

Keep that in mind next time you make a "minor" edit: if the post is still an eye-sore after you're done, your name is displayed below it until someone else steps in to finish cleaning up the mess.

FWIW: I have, in the past, suggested that a more subtle display (such as the one you suggested) might go a long way toward easing the tension some users feel toward others editing their work. I've come to accept that's not such a great idea. Users on these sites *must* become comfortable with others editing their posts, and editors *must* be willing to take some responsibility for what they edit.

Answer (score 9):

Editors are *hugely* important -- they are peer reviewing your posts, just like other programmers peer review your code.

[image]

Together, we make better posts!