# Reduce visibility of the "edited" indicator on a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are editor names displayed so prominently?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83196/why-are-editor-names-displayed-so-prominently)

Currently, a question that has been edited appears as follows:

[image: big notice that question has been edited]

This is odd to me, because the fact that a question has been edited generally isn't that important. It's only relevant to those initially answering the questions, and even then it's only relevant when the editing changed the question for the worse, which is the minority situation. It does, however, needlessly highlight the fact that higher-rep SO users are constantly fixing questions, which only serves to give this place a [wikipedia-like reputation](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4248392), and not in a good way. In that light, having a prominent "edited" badge is not a good thing.

So, I wanted to ask, **could we significantly reduce the visibility of the question "edited" indicator?**

Comment: *"It does, however, needlessly highlight the fact that higher-rep SO users are constantly fixing questions"* ... You make it sound as if that's a bad thing. I think they deserve some credit there.

Comment: "because the fact that a question has been edited generally isn't that important". I must be reading all the other questions... the ones that severely need editing.

Comment: I agree they should get some credit, but to get what is essentially co-authorship just for what can essentially be just adding a tag seems somewhat excessive to me.

Comment: So, you want to have degrees of editing (or rather, degrees of contribution displayed)?

Comment: In the example you cited I think it's less a question of who gets the credit and more a question of who gets the blame.  If that's a real question somewhere, please link to it so we can smite it.

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83196/why-are-editor-names-displayed-so-prominentl

Comment: @Oded - I would rather see degrees of visibility. It makes sense to me that the author of the question be given more credit than those that edit it. As it stands, they get what appears to be equal credit.

Comment: What about a terrible question, terribly tagged, that an editor improved into a great question with good tagging? And of course, how is this to be judged?

Comment: I've seen quite a few questions in which the editor put significantly more work into the question than the actual asker did.  You make it seem like all edits are minor.  Many are not.

Comment: @Oded - That's very rare. It's often a terrible question, terribly tagged, that an editor improved into a terrible—but understandable—question, with good tags.

Comment: @eykanal It's actually not that rare.  Perhaps you should spend some time lurking in the /review tool.  Also note that there are people who can, and do, turn awful questions into rather good ones, which often takes quite a bit of effort (relative to the original question).

Comment: Is anybody but me dying to click the (non-existent) revisions link to read the (non-existent) original version of the chzberger post?

Comment: @eykanal I don't think it's all that rare.

Comment: And keep in mind that most of the higher-rep users don't get any reward for their edits. That is, other than the reward of seeing a question's quality increase, thereby contributing to the overall quality of the site as a whole. If that does not deserve some form of recognition then I don't know what does.

Comment: I sort of agree with this -- the editor's user card doesn't need to be quite as prominent as the OP's, but the HN post you linked to in order to back up your argument has _nothing whatsoever_ to do with edits. It's about a _locked_ post.

Comment: How can you possibly think that a "Wikipedia-like" reputation is a *bad thing*? Wikipedia is one of the most popular websites in the history of the Internet. Why would you consider this a problem? Also, your link doesn't make sense in this context. It's about moderators locking posts, it has nothing at all to do with Wiki-style editing.

Comment: @meagar - I'm referring to the reputation for being led by a completely bureaucratic power-hungry group, not to it's success as a website.

Comment: ... You think Stack Overflow has a reputation for being "led by a completely bureaucratic power-hungry group" ...of *editors*? I don't quite know what to say to that.

Comment: @bart - I'm not talking about rep, I'm just referring to giving credit to the questioner. I guess my premise is flawed.

Comment: Nevermind that the top responses in the link you posted are all *in support of Stack Overflow's moderator* in locking that post.

Comment: "Power-hungry" - ha. Cue massive downvotes in 5...4...

Comment: @meagar - No. I'm saying that I've seen more than a few complaints online recently that SO is gaining a reputation for having it's fair share of bureaucratic power-hungry high-rep *mods*, and since most edits come from those with at least some mod privileges (2k+), this probably isn't helping.

Comment: @eykanal I'm saying that we (yes, I'm a fairly active editor as well) don't do it for any other reason than to keep the quality of this site up. We spend our time on that and don't get anything in return. I think these efforts should be acknowledged and shown. If anything to indicate that this is possible. And to describe those who do their best to keep SO/SE at the high level of quality it still achieves as a "bureaucratic power-hungry group" is misguided at best.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Mehh, what can I do? I'm not trying to make the complaint, I'm trying to give less fodder to those who do. Feel free to downvote, it's a free internets.

Comment: @eykanal I already did, because I disagree with your suggestion. My comment was reflecting the fact that making such allegations does not, in any way, add strength to your argument, and is more likely to yield a less favorable response.

Comment: Anybody who is uncomfortable with having their content edited either needs to *post better content* or [not post here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing). Trying to down-play the fact that your stuff can be edited would be more or less lying to our new users. People need to know they're contributing to a collaboratively-edited site *before* they post. If Stack Overflow gains a reputation for being collaboratively edited, this is a good thing.

Comment: @Bart - You're preaching to the choir. I didn't say "I have these complaints", I said "some do, and we can do this to help mitigate it." [I've edited as well, though not so much lately.](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white?userid=168775).

Comment: If some do, then perhaps SO is not for them. I don't think we should let our quality drop to cater for more people. And with 5.6k question's a day, I think we're still doing just fine. We're not perfect, but we're not as bad as "some" have you believe either.

Comment: You might want to take a look at _userscripts_. They allow you to modify stuff on websites (in this case CSS). This is usually the solution to implement things that the majority disagree with

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Editing is a very important aspect of the site, and an aspect that does need some community review. So I think it's important for both anonymous viewers *and* community members to see that stuff has been edited.

For anonymous viewers it drives home the point that content here can be edited; and *corrected*. This post isn't just what some jerk barfed out onto the internet (like so so many other sites), it's actually been reviewed, and hopefully improved, by other members.

For community members it gives an opportunity to see what changed; if the change was good, then cool. Maybe you'll learn how editing is supposed to work from seeing what others do. If the change was bad, it can be rolled back, or the post can be flagged for moderator attention if it appears someone is abusing edits.

Comment: It tells you that you're looking at what X thought Y was saying, rather than what Y said.  That's an important distinction.

Comment: @Servy not always, I'd say more often than not edits don't interpret gibberish but rather fix up obvious mistakes.

Comment: Sometimes it's true and sometimes it's not.  Yes, there are certainly cases where the editor never makes any judgement calls about what the OP meant.  My point was that it happens often enough that when there is a question about what the OP meant, it's often worthwhile to review the edit history.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the fact that it has been edited is often very important. Consider that the things you find useful in a site do not necessarily match the general consensus. It's hard to understand why the pros you outline must be pros for all of us... if you don't care about the fact that a question has been edited, then ignore it.

Are we talking about you wishing to hide the fact that YOUR question has been edited?

In any case do you really think this is fair to people who have already read the question and will assume they don't have to read it again? What if that leads them down the wrong path, wasted effort, misunderstanding, even bickering? I don't want to speak for everyone, but making edits visible is very valuable to a lot of us.

Answer (score -7):

One possible solution would be to use the same indicator as used for edited comments:

[image: smaller edit indicator]

I see the "Pros" as follows:

1. It's less visible
2. It's subtle
3. It's consistent
4. It reduces the visibility of edits by pro users

The "Con" is that it's harder to click, but that's a small price to pay for a more streamlined UI.

Comment: That would indicate to me that the OP was the editor. There is value in showing users that edits are made by _everyone_.

Comment: Good point, not sure what a good way to do that would be. This was just a starting point.